# How can I limit the user from going to specific component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router, mern

I have 2 questions.

1.) How can I make the localhost default to

> http://localhost:3000/login

because my end point for login is that.

2.) How can block admin if he didn't login propely, I've done the small part by using this

```
<Route path="/home">{admin ? <Home /> : <Login />}</Route>
```

but what if I have a bunch of components?

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css'
import Sidebar from './components/sidemenu/Sidebar'
import Home from './pages/home/Home'
import Login from './pages/login/Login'
import NewProduct from './pages/newProduct/NewProduct'
import NewUser from './pages/newUser/NewUser'
import ProductList from './pages/product/ProductList'
import Product from './pages/productItem/Product'
import User from './pages/user/User'
import UserList from './pages/userList/UserList'
function App() {
  const admin = useSelector((state) => state.user?.currentUser?.isAdmin)

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login">
          <Login />
        </Route>
         {/* <Route path="/home">{admin ? <Home /> : <Login />}</Route> */}
        {admin && (
          <>
            <div className="container">
              <Sidebar />
              <Route path="/">
                <Home />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/users">
                <UserList />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/user/:userId">
                <User />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/newUser">
                <NewUser />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/products">
                <ProductList />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/products/:productId">
                <Product />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/newproduct">
                <NewProduct />
              </Route>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App
```

I've tried the

```
{admin && (<> 
     ......
 </>)}
```

but when I write the endpoint in the browser, it still allows me to enter

Answer (score 1):

create a component to check whether user has permission or not,

like this one:

```js
import React from "react";
import {Route, Redirect} from "react-router-dom";

export default function PrivateRoute({component: Component, auth, ...rest}) {
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
            auth? (
                <Component {...props}/>
            ) : (
                <Redirect to="/login"/>
            )
        )}
        />
    )
}
```

and you can use it like this:

```js
...
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" auth={admin} component={Dashboard}/>
</Switch>
...
```